# Fiddler use Inspector Raw by default

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler is awesome. But one thing that bugs me is that every time I double click a Session it defaults to opening the Inspectors tab and tries to guess what inspector to show. I want it to always show me the Raw inspector for both Request and Response.

Is there any way to make Fiddler always default to this?

Comment: using 2.2.9.6 here. it does always show raw request and response header

Comment: I'm using 2.2.9.7 and it is not. Did you somehow customize your environment?

Comment: I think my problem is the double click. If I open a session and select the Raw inspector for both, then for any new session if I SINGLE click on them it opens it with the Raw inspectors. My bad, this works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can accomplish what I am after by simply single clicking a session. The first time I need to select Raw for both Request and Response, then single clicking any future sessions leaves them selected. Good enough.

As EricLaw points out the true solution to this is possible and very simple:

You can set the "default active" request and response inspectors like this: Click Rules > Customize Rules, and scroll down to the OnBoot handler and uncomment the lines that set the default Inspectors. Then change the two instances of the text "HEADERS" to "RAW".

Comment: FWIW, you can also set the "default active" request and response inspectors. Click Rules > Customize Rules, and scroll down to the OnBoot handler and uncomment the lines that set the default Inspectors.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I do see how to do that, but it doesn't seem to affect the Double Click action. I now have it setup so that a single click on a session shows raw by default, but a double click still results in TextView for request and Headers for response.

Comment: When a double-click/enter invocation occurs, each editor gets to "vote" on how much it wants a given response based on the MIME type (the idea being that certain inspectors naturally are more suitable for certain requests/responses). In the upcoming Fiddler v2.3.3.3, I'll add a new preference that allows you to control the "vote" of the RAW tab such that you can kick it up as high as you want.

Comment: Version 2.3.3.3 is now available at http://getfiddler.com. In the QuickExec box, type PREFS SET fiddler.ui.inspectors.request.alwaysuse RAW

Comment: Perfect! What amazing responsiveness. Admirable. Thank you Eric.

Comment: @EricLaw Beautiful - Thanks very much - that is exactly how i want it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing about:config using QuickExec box then adding preferences one by one on the pictures which are below:

[image]
[image]

Or Eric Law comment:

[image]

Also I wanted to put HTTP METHOD information as an column:

[image]